# unload filepicker from a page

Tags: filepicker.io

Is there a way to unload filepicker from a webpage?

I'm building an app using Meteor. I want to give only logged in users to have access to filepicker. Each use gets his own unique key. I want to destroy all references to filepicker once the user logs out.

Apart from the JS and the initialized filepicker object, I noticed there is an iframe being introduced by filepicker. Are there any more artifacts being loaded into browser as part of filepicker? Is there a safe way to unload all the filepicker specific elements from the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe is used for cross-domain communication, and will not leak any information, etc. if it remains in. However, if you want to remove all elements introduced by Filepicker.io, then yes deleting the script tag and the `filepicker` js object, along with the `filepicker_comm_iframe` should do the trick

Comment: But what if you simply want to "reload" filepicker. Deleting filepicker is easy enough, but how do bring it back?